# mongodb aggregation with array and lookup

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB collection with documents in the following format
collection name called post

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c88b225fac24431d947abad"),
    "user_id" : "5c87ad6c623f1e2bd4d041d0",
    "post_likes" : [ 
        {
            "post_user_id" : "5c87ad6c623f1e2bd4d041d0",
            "like_status" : true
        }, 
        {
            "post_user_id" : "5c88b42b71611926c055508b",
            "like_status" : true
        }
    ],
    "post_comments" : [ 
        {
            "comment_user_id" : "5c87ad6c623f1e2bd4d041d0",
            "comment_like" : "",
            "comment_description" : ""
        }, 
        {
            "comment_user_id" : "5c88b42b71611926c055508b",
            "comment_like" : "",
            "comment_description" : "nice post"
        }
    ]
}
```

i have another collection name called user_ptofile_info

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c923682c088564cf01056cb"),
    "user_id" : "5c87ad6c623f1e2bd4d041d0",
    "image_url" : "image/url",
    "user_name":"xxxxxxxx",
    "created_at" : "",
    "updated_at" : ""
}
```

requested output like
**note:the post_user_id from user_ptofile_info and user_id from post are lookup and i need total count for post_likes and post comments also**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c88b225fac24431d947abad"),
    "user_id" : "5c87ad6c623f1e2bd4d041d0",
    "post_likes" : [ 
        {
            "post_user_id" : "5c87ad6c623f1e2bd4d041d0",
            "like_status" : true,
            "image_url" : "image/url",
            "user_name":"xxxxxxxx",
        }, 
        {
            "post_user_id" : "5c88b42b71611926c055508b",
            "like_status" : true,
            "image_url" : "image/url",
            "user_name":"xxxxxxxx",
        }
    ],
    "post_comments" : [ 
        {
            "comment_user_id" : "5c87ad6c623f1e2bd4d041d0",
            "comment_like" : "",
            "comment_description" : ""
        }, 
        {
            "comment_user_id" : "5c88b42b71611926c055508b",
            "comment_like" : "",
            "comment_description" : "nice post"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you show what you have tried

Answer (score 1):

You can use below aggregation:

```
db.post.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "user_profile_info",
            let: { user_ids: "$post_likes.post_user_id" },
            pipeline: [
                { $match: { $expr: { $in: [ "$user_id", "$$user_ids" ] } } },
                { 
                    $project: {
                        post_user_id: "$user_id",
                        image_url: 1,
                        user_name: 1                        
                    }  
                }
            ],
            as: "users"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            user_id: 1,
            post_likes: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$users",
                    as: "user",
                    in: {
                        post_user_id: "$$user.post_user_id",
                        image_url: "$$user.image_url",
                        user_name: "$$user.user_name",
                        like_status: {
                            $let: { 
                                vars: { 
                                    like: { 
                                        $arrayElemAt: [ 
                                            { $filter: { input: "$post_likes", as: "pl", cond: { $eq: [ "$$pl.post_user_id", "$$user.post_user_id" ] } } }, 0 
                                        ] 
                                    } 
                                },
                                in: "$$like.like_status"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            post_comments: 1
        }
    }
])
```

[$lookup with custom pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) (MongoDB 3.6 or newer) will allow you to get the data from `user_profile_info` for all users that are present in `post_likes` array. Then you need to "merge" `users` array with `post_likes` to get `like_status`. Since you have two arrays and you know that the same `post_user_id` appears in both of them you can use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) with [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) and [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) to combine the data from both arrays.

Comment: hi mickl still i facing some issues like  : **  Mongo Server error (MongoCommandException): Command failed with error 40081 (Location40081): '$in requires an array as a second argument, found: missing' on server localhost:27017. **  i thought its happening because of some times the post_likes array may be empty or the key may not present this same condition for post_comments also

Comment: @s.chandransha yes, definitely that's the reason. What should happen for empty `post_likes` ? Can you filter them out ?

Comment: i done like this  let: { user_ids: {$cond: {if: { $isArray:"$post_likes" },then: "$post_likes.post_user_id",else: []}}} this is working for me is that correct way to approach

Comment: @s.chandransha should be fine